# Using $timeout for repetitive rest calls in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to implement a service which makes a rest call every 5 seconds. Previously I was using $interval but I realized using could get in troubles if a request takes longer than 5 sec because of internet connection problems.

```
    service.fetchData= function () {
        //UpdateHandler is my handler function which just fills my json array
        restApiService.requestFromApi("REST" + '?latitude=' + latestCoords.latitude + '&longitude=' + latestCoords.longitude + '&radius=' + config.radiusInMetres, updateHandler);
    };

    $timeout(service.fetchData, 5000);
```

fetchData is still called just once.

How can we use timeout for multiple calls and using promises(I am not very familiar with promises)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick to `$timeout`, you should call the function recursively, with a timeout, then request to `API` is finished.

```
service.fetchData= function fetchData() {
    //UpdateHandler is my handler function which just fills my json array
    restApiService.requestFromApi("REST" + '?latitude=' + latestCoords.latitude + '&longitude=' + latestCoords.longitude + '&radius=' + config.radiusInMetres, updateHandler)
    .finally(function(){ 
          $timeout(fetchData, 5000)// Call new fetchData after finish previous
         });
};

$timeout(service.fetchData, 5000);
```

Example

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function(restApiService, $timeout) {
    var vm = this;
    this.fetchData = function() {
      console.log("start request");
      restApiService.requestFromApi("data")
        .then(function() {
          console.log("success response");
        })
        .finally(function() {
          console.log("request again");
          fetchByTimeout();// Call new fetchData after finish previous
        });
    };

    function fetchByTimeout() {
      $timeout(vm.fetchData, 5000);
    }
    fetchByTimeout();
  })
  // Service for simulate long API call
  .service("restApiService", function($q, $timeout) {
    return {
      requestFromApi: function(request) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        //simulate 10 seconds API call
        $timeout(defer.resolve, 10000);
        return defer.promise;
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While using finally, I often get this error                                             Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'finally' of undefined(…)

Comment: @AbdulSalamShaikh Function `requestFromApi` need return a promise. Show code for `requestFromApi` function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40630494/cannot-read-property-finally-of-undefined-while-trying-to-make-rest-call

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `$timeOut` for multiple calls.As per the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout), the return value of calling $timeout is a promise, which will be resolved when the delay has passed and the timeout function, if provided, is executed. In short, it will be executed once, after the time delay has lapsed

What you were previously using `$interval` is correct for your requirement. To avoid the problem that you are suggesting ( slow internet, and a new call before the previous is completed), use a flag.

```
//if(flag is false)
// set flag to true and make http call 
// upon return from call, set flag to false
```

Now use this login within your `$interval` function call. Hope this helps.

Comment: How can i use incorporate promise to this code, if you can throw some light on that ?

Comment: The promise would be returned from a service where the http call should be made. The flag should be in your controller which calls the service. And the $interval also within controller which would call the service based on the flag condition

Answer (score 0):

For multiple calls you must use $interval.

```
var myapp = angular.module("myapp", []);

myapp.controller("MyController", function($scope, $interval){

    $interval(isLoggedIn, 5000);

});

function isLoggedIn() {
    console.log("Interval occurred");
    // call your service method`enter code here` here
}
```

---

For Promise in angularJs check the link...

http://haroldrv.com/2015/02/understanding-angularjs-q-service-and-promises/